# Piping data from the host into docker container command not working with docker machine

Tags: linux, docker, pipe, docker-machine

I'm running Docker on Windows 10 hosted using [docker-machine](https://docs.docker.com/machine/). I'm trying to pipe data from host into a container spawn with 'docker run' with this command:

```
echo test | docker run -i ubuntu:16.04 cat -
```

I'd expect this command to output 'test' to the stdout, but all it does is print a blank line:

```
jannis MINGW64 ~
$ echo test | docker run -i ubuntu:16.04 cat -

jannis MINGW64 ~
$
```

However when I ssh into the docker-machine the command works as expected:

```
jannis MINGW64 ~
$ docker-machine ssh
                        ##         .
                  ## ## ##        ==
               ## ## ## ## ##    ===
           /"""""""""""""""""\___/ ===
      ~~~ {~~ ~~~~ ~~~ ~~~~ ~~~ ~ /  ===- ~~~
           \______ o           __/
             \    \         __/
              \____\_______/
 _                 _   ____     _            _
| |__   ___   ___ | |_|___ \ __| | ___   ___| | _____ _ __
| '_ \ / _ \ / _ \| __| __) / _` |/ _ \ / __| |/ / _ \ '__|
| |_) | (_) | (_) | |_ / __/ (_| | (_) | (__|   <  __/ |
|_.__/ \___/ \___/ \__|_____\__,_|\___/ \___|_|\_\___|_|
Boot2Docker version 17.06.1-ce, build HEAD : 80114bc - Fri Aug 18 17:58:04 UTC 2017
Docker version 17.06.1-ce, build 874a737
docker@default:~$ echo test | docker run -i ubuntu:16.04 cat -
test
```

Can someone tell me:

1. Why piping into a container within docker-machine doesn't work? Is this a bug?
2. Is there a workaround for this (apart from the one provided above - ssh into the docker-machine VM)?

PS I'm using [GitBash environment](https://git-for-windows.github.io/) (based on [MSYS2](http://www.msys2.org/)/[MINGW](http://www.mingw.org/)) on my Windows 10 machine. Version info:

```
jannis MINGW64 ~
$ uname -a
MINGW64_NT-10.0 jannis 2.6.1(0.306/5/3) 2017-01-14 09:41 x86_64 Msys

jannis MINGW64 ~
$ docker version
Client:
 Version:      17.06.0-ce
 API version:  1.30
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   02c1d87
 Built:        Fri Jun 23 21:30:30 2017
 OS/Arch:      windows/amd64

Server:
 Version:      17.06.1-ce
 API version:  1.30 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   874a737
 Built:        Thu Aug 17 22:54:55 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: false
```

Comment: Do one thing install Git Bash, and try inside Git bash?

Comment: @TarunLalwani this is GitBash. I'll edit my post.

Comment: @TarunLalwani In the end your tip helped me solve this issue. Running the command in **raw** GitBash console (not run through ConEmu) helped me nail the root cause. See my edited answer for details

Comment: It should work these days, just keep it -i and not -it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## EDIT 2-11-2017

Turns out it was a problem with the terminal I'm using ([ConEmu](https://conemu.github.io/)). Or to be more exact the [special case](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/28cca5dcaa2aa21123805d7f2d51916ea1f38d71/pkg/term/term_windows.go#L74) in Docker's codebase dedicated to ConEmu.

Following the workaround suggested in [this comment](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/28814#issuecomment-295629353) I managed to make piping work:

> As a workaround, disabling `ConEmu Settings -> Features -> ANSI and xterm sequences` helped me.

Relevant links:

- My ticket in docker-machine: https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/4235
- Ticket in ConEmu: https://github.com/Maximus5/ConEmu/issues/958
- Ticket in Docker: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/28814

## ORIGINAL ANSWER

I've posted [a bug](https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/4235) in `docker-machine`'s issuetracker, we'll see what they say.

Currently I've ended up with a workaround. I'm saving the payload I want piped to a local file, then transferring the file into the container with [`docker cp`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/) and next piping it locally within container.

To sum up:

What I want to do and doesn't work with `docker-machine` is:

```
echo piped content | docker run -i ubuntu:16.04 cat -
```

Instead I do this:

```
jannis MINGW64 ~
$ docker create --name test-container ubuntu:16.04 sh -c 'cat - < /tmp/emulatedpipe'
a6eaf1e5f143113bcffa9df66a47b37c124cd34447b670480b5f096d45b7b162

jannis MINGW64 ~
$ echo piped content > emulatedpipe

jannis MINGW64 ~
$ docker cp emulatedpipe test-container:/tmp

jannis MINGW64 ~
$ docker start -i test-container
piped content
```